# Can I specify callback URL on built-in OIDC Authentication call from Blazor static web app WASM?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, blazor, openid-connect, blazor-webassembly, azure-static-web-app

I call "/.auth/login/google" (or other providers) from my Blazor static web app. Once the user consents, control is routed back to the index page. Is there a way to specify that I'd like a different return page, e.g. via something like "/.auth/login/google?callback=http..."?

Comment: Have you tried this and it doesn't work?  This current issue raised by me on the AzureAD  Github Repo may "answer" your question - https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/issues/1968 - it's been classified as a bug.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Inside of an Azure Static Web App (saying Static Blazor App I am assuming that you are using an Azure Static Web App) the query param is: `post_login_redirect_uri` rather than the `callback` that you are using.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/authentication-authorization#set-up-post-sign-in-redirect

The route to the redirect page is relative to the login page itself so if you have 2 routes in your BLazor app:

- index
- redirect

then the link to the login page would be `/.auth/login/google?post_login_redirect_uri=/redirect`